# Apache Avro IPC server side async

Tags: java, ipc, avro, rpc

I'm trying to implement an async server application using Avro IPC. As far as I've researched, it is possible to make client async calls by calling the method of generated Callback protocol classes like this:

My generated protocol class:

```
@org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
public interface TestProtocol {
  public static final org.apache.avro.Protocol PROTOCOL = /*ommited*/;
  
  ResponseTest send(MessageTest TestMsg);

  @org.apache.avro.specific.AvroGenerated
  public interface Callback extends TestProtocol {
    public static final org.apache.avro.Protocol PROTOCOL = TestProtocol.PROTOCOL;

    void send(MessageTest TestMsg, org.apache.avro.ipc.Callback<ResponseTest> callback) throws java.io.IOException;
  }
}
```

And implementation of this code

```
public final class TestProtocolImplAsync implements TestProtocol.Callback {

  @Override
  public @NotNull ResponseTest send(@NotNull MessageTest TestMsg) {
    return new ResponseTest("Sync call");
  }

  @Override
  public void send(@NotNull MessageTest TestMsg,
                   @NotNull org.apache.avro.ipc.Callback<ResponseTest> callback) {
    callback.handleResult(new ResponseTest("Async call"));
  }
}
```

The implementation of TestProtocol is binded to TestProtocolImpl on server side. However, while calling it on client side this way:

```
SpecificRequestor.getClient(TestProtocol.Callback.class, client).send(new MessageTest(/*params*/), new Callback<ResponseTest>() {
      @Override
      public void handleResult(@NotNull ResponseTest result) {
        System.out.println(result.toString());
      }

      @Override
      public void handleError(@NotNull Throwable error) {
        //whatever
      }
    })
```

I keep getting sync server method called. I haven't found any info about this in documentation, but am I right that callback method is only to be implemented on async client side, not server, and it is impossible to process request on server asyncrously this way and call callback method from server side? Or am I missing something in my server settings?